# How to organise common dependencies for Java 9 modules?

Tags: java, maven

For now I have maven project with several maven modules:

- Root module, used as parent module for all other modules;
- Some child modules, some of them depending on others.

For each module, except the root one, I've created `module-info.java`, where I've listed proper dependencies.

But I have some dependencies, required by any module. In maven, I've put them in `dependencies` section of the root `pom.xml`.

Is it possible to write them only once in root module's `module-info.java`, and then import it to submodules?

I know about command `requires transitive ...`, but I don't know how to make module-info, created in src/java directory of my root module, accessible by it's children's module-infos.

Comment: First your root module will never contain code which includes `module-info.java` because a root module is of type `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. Furthermore the `module-info.java` should be located into `src/main/java` . And no it's not possible to define it into the root module. A `module-info.java` file describes in the end a jar file (boundaries of it)...

Comment: This means that each of your modules (child) is a separate module (jar) file which must has a module-info.java file and describes what it's need and what it's using... The dependencies in your pom file are something different. They describe how to identify the jar file which is used. And they need to be modules as well...

Comment: Anyway: I have several child modules, any of them uses several same dependencies.
I could write for any of them: `requires aaa; requires bbb; requires ccc;`
But I want to write it in the only one place, and share between all my child modules.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can't share module-info file for several childs. If you really that several of them need to have the same deps (modules) it could be the case that you might need to combine them into one ..but I can't make a educated guess cause I don't know your code.

Comment: For example, I need `requires kotlin.stdlib; requires io.reactivex.rxjava2;" and so on in each module, because I use Kotlin and Rxjava everywhere.